# scaling an azure website

Tags: asp.net, iis, azure, web

I have a Standard website in Azure with a small instance, (1 core and 1.75 GB memory). It seems to be coping fine and handling the requests smoothly, although I am expecting a lot more  within the week.

It is unclear though under what circumstances I should be looking to scale the instance size to the next level ie to Medium. (Besides MemoryWorkingSet of course, rather obvious :))

ie. Will moving up to a Medium instance resolve high CPU time ?
What other telltales should I be watching for ?

I am NOT comfortable scaling the number of instances to more than one at the moment until I resolve some cache issues.

I think the key point I am trying to understand is the link between the metrics provided and the means of scaling available regardless of it being scaled horizontally or vertically.

I am trying to keep the average response time as low as possible as the number of users that interact with the website increase.

Which of the other metrics will alert me when the load on the server is getting to its limits & I will need to scale Vertically ?

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind scaling in Azure is to scale horizontally, i.e. add more instances. Azure can do this for you automatically. If you can't add more instances, Azure can't do the scaling for you automatically.

You can move to Medium instance, overall capacity will increase, but it is impossible to say what your application will require under heavy load. I suggest you run profiler and load test to find out the weak parts of your app and improve these before you have an actual increase in useage.

Comment: I think the key point I am trying to understand is the link between the metrics provided and the means of scaling available regardless of it being scaled horizontally or vertically.